# WSGI Exception - Port block

Tags: python, django, linux

I probably should go to Server Fault with this, but I don't know how to exactly spell the problem, it seems that port 80 on my machine(Xubuntu 9.10) is blocked by something, the only clue I've got is this:

```
Django version 1.2.3, using settings 'settings'
Development server is running at http://0.0.0.0:80/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: You don't have permission to access that port.
```

Maybe someone tripped on something similar in the past?

Comment: The user you're running django's server as doesn't have the permissions it needs. You may need to run it as root, or pick a port above 1024 for your testing server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Error: You don't have permission to access that port"

That's the bottom line.  You don't have access.

Port 80 requires a privileged process like Apache.  The built-in server with Django is not privileged and should not be used for anything but development.